# Where do I get OkHttpClient version compiled in jdk 1.6? I am getting UnsupportedClassVersionError while running it on WAS 7

Tags: java, okhttp

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=okhttp3/MediaType, offset=6
This is the exception I am getting when running the code on WAS 7. I think the okhttp code was compiled using Java 7 or some higher version and when I am trying to use it on WAS 7 which uses java 6. 
I am using the latest jar (v 3.2) from
http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one. OkHttpClient required Java7 since 2012. It uses APIs available only in Java7 and later (e.g. syncFlush API on DeflaterOutputStream, as mentioned in [github commit that enforced compilation against java7](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/fc01d7e54dd52bf454c0230009834ae30a93538d)).

You will need to use different HTTP library in Java6. E.g. Apache HttpClient, or java.net.URL.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. And that also means WebSphere Servers 7.x.x cannot use OkHttpClient. Both WAS 7.x.x & WAS 8.0.x uses Java 6. WebSphere 8.5.x uses Java 7. They should consider a version compiled in java 6 for all the WAS 7 & 8 people.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002

Comment: @Yash An issue has been opened (back on 5 Sep 2012) concerning the support of Java < 7. It has been closed with *"... you need to use Java 7."*. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/18